# GUI SCP Client?

Tags: 16.04, ssh, scp

Is there a SCP Client like WinSCP just for Linux?

it has to support SCP and not SFTP as the other questions suggested

as the Server I have to connect to, only understands ssh and scp no sftp

its a embedded device with limited capabilities based on some busybox installation

Comment: FAR manager https://github.com/elfmz/far2l  supports plain SCP

Answer (score 3):

Try the "connect to server" function in the places menu in Ubuntu Mate.  Other versions of ubuntu have the same function though I'm not sure where, per version. in your file manager, under "File" there should be a "Connect to server" option.

Youll get a window like this, where you can supply user credentials, and set up book marks, to get back to the same locations.[image]

You can also select various protocols like FTP. HTTP/s, AFP, SSH (the protocol winscp uses)

Comment: (on my ubuntu 16.04 it doest show a Type dropdown, it only allows me to use urls i tried scp://ip and ssh://ip)
sorry but it doesnt support scp:// protocoll which is been used by winscp
and 
ssh:// is not working after login the server kicks me for "Unknown error, connection lost" 
while on winscp it works

Comment: scp is ssh. ...

Comment: how can i get a more verbose error then, maybe that would help?

Comment: it asks me to trust the source after that I can enter the Password and after the "login process"
i just get this error
http://imgur.com/a/95mHf

i can connect to the server with the terminal ssh client though without any problems
and use scp from cmdline

Comment: Caja requires gvfs-backends` to open the “Network” folder and explore samba share.   if youre getting failure due to unknown connectivity issue, I would beging there. `sudo apt-get install gvfs-backends`  You might be saying: but I dont use caja. (I use caja) or you might say, my file manager is gnome, or unity, or... something else. I would look at the network dependencies for the file manager.

Comment: GVFS (via Nautilus) only supports SFTP which is not the same as SCP. -1